# How do I disable a button depending on a variable value?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, button

I'm pretty new at JavaScript. I have a variable and two buttons to add or minus 1 from that variable, which works; However I want to make is so that when the variable `= 0` the minus button disables, so the variable wont go below 0.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = 0;
        var add = function(valueToAdd) {
            a += valueToAdd;
            document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Value:<span id="Value">0</span>
    <button type="button" id = add onclick="javascript:add(1)">+</button>
    <button type="button" id = minus onclick="javascript:add(-1)">-</button>
</body>
```

Comment: ok so what did you do?

Comment: Last line of the add function: `document.getElementById("minus").disabled = (a==0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 0;
    var add = function(valueToAdd){
        a += valueToAdd;
        document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;

        if(a == 0) {
            document.getElementById('minus').disabled = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('minus').disabled = false;
        }
    }    

</script>

</head>

<body>
    Value:<span id="Value">0</span>
    <button type="button" id = add onclick="javascript:add(1)">+</button>
    <button type="button" id = minus onclick="javascript:add(-1)">-</button>


</body>
```

Comment: Also remember that since the intial value will be zero, `This <button type="button" id = minus onclick="javascript:add(-1)">-</button>`
 neeeds to be this: `<button type="button" id = minus onclick="javascript:add(-1)" disabled>-</button>`

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
a = Math.max(0, a+valueToAdd); // prevents a from dropping below 0
document.getElementById('minus').disabled = !a; // disables the minus button if a = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `disabled` attribute:

```
var add = function(valueToAdd)
{
        document.getElementById('minus').disabled = (a+valueToAdd == 0);
        a += valueToAdd;
        document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `disabled` attribute of the button element.

```
var a = 0;
var add = function(valueToAdd) {
    a += valueToAdd;
    document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;

    // Add this line, it will disable when a is 0
    document.getElementById("minus").disabled = (a==0);
}
```

You should also update your button code. The `javascript:` handler is not required, and your id attributes should be quoted.

```
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="add(1)">+</button>
<button type="button" id="minus" onclick="add(-1)" disabled="disabled">-</button>
```

I have also added the `disabled="disabled"` to the minus button, because the initial value will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

First: Please put quotes around your ids, and remove the inline js:

```
<button type="button" id="add">+</button>
<button type="button" id="minus">-</button>
```

Next:

Write an event handler for the button clicks:

```
var val = document.getElementById('Value');
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var subs = document.getElementById('minus');
var eventHandler = function(event) {
    var value = parseInt(val.innerText || val.innerHTML);
    if(this.id === 'add') { value++; }
    else if(this.id === 'minus') { value--;}
    val.innerHTML = value;
    if(value <= 0) {
        subs.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        subs.disabled = false;
    }
};
```

Then hook the eventHandler into the buttons:

```
add.onclick = eventHandler;
subs.onclick = eventHandler;
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/wevG4/